# Strange thread behavior with onClickListener

Tags: android, multithreading, view

I am trying to change the background of a button to 'pressed' for 1 second, then change that background back to 'default'. I created one Thread called sleeper that simply sleeps for 1 second. Below is the method I am using. The strange thing is, the buttons background doesn't change until the sleeper thread is done sleeping. I know threads are never guarenteed to start at any given time but since I am setting the background of the button before starting the Thread I figured this should work.

```
private void handleButtonPress(View button, int buttonPressedID,
        int buttonNormalID) {

    button.setBackgroundResource(buttonPressedID);
    Sleeper sleeper = new Sleeper();
    sleeper.start();
    try {
        sleeper.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Thanks for having a look!

Comment: Trouble is, that your sleeper blocks the UI thread (join waits for sleeper to be finished) for that duration before your button background gets updated.

Comment: You're going to block the UI thread on `join`. Don't do that. Get a handler to the UI thread, set the button background, then postDelayed on the handler to change it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please simply use a Handler for that:

```
Handler h = new Handler();

h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do your delayed stuff here
    }
}, 1000); // execute the code inside run() after 1000ms
```

Comment: You are right, my suggestion of using a handler in this case is definitely "not a useful answer".

Comment: I'm just guessing but probably what Andy meant was it doesn't answer the "why". Simply providing code usually isn't useful in helping a person learn what they did wrong.

Comment: Well, if you hover the downvote button it actually says what its supposed to be used for. And I don't think my answer is not useful. I especially love downvotes like that from people who did not contribute anything.

Comment: Phil's solution does work for me. Below is the source, sorry I have no idea how to format a comment!

Comment: private void handleButtonPress(final View button,
   final int buttonPressedID,
   final int buttonNormalID) {

  button.setBackgroundResource(buttonPressedID);  
  Handler h = new Handler();
  h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
    button.setBackgroundResource(buttonNormalID);
      }
  }, 1000);
 }

Comment: Thank you Jason. So definitely a "useless" answer of mine. Haters gonna hate I suppose.