# Supporting multiple Screen sizes with Button design

Tags: android, button, photoshop

I have created a button in Photoshop. The problem is that when I test app from a big screen phone everything is good, but when I test in smaller phone then button is very big. How can I make good size button for every phone sizes?

Comment: please show your  code

Answer (score 1):

I suppose by "I designed a button in Photoshop" you mean that you designed its background-image.

The size of a Button is actually **not necessarily dependent on the size of the background** image. You can control the size of your button via its properties that can be set in the layout.xml file (or in code).

In this simple example the Button will always use up exactly half of the parent layouts width (LinearLyout).
(Watch the "weightSum" and "weight" properties).

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Of course, there are many more ways and properties of how to adjust your layout to different screen sizes, this should just give you a brief example of how it could be done.
For more information, check out this tutorial from the Google-Android-Developer page:

**Supporting Multiple Screen Sizes** (especially Density-Independence should be interesting for you)

> http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Don't mean to hate on ya, but when you're using `layout_weights`, set `android:layout_width="0dp"`. And, in case of a LinearLayout with vertical orientation, `android:layout_height="0dp"`.

Comment: Non taken, is it bad style to do otherwise?

Comment: Although Android Lint lists using `0dp` as a performance enhancer, the reasoning is actually quite logical. If you are using `layout_weights` to control the distribution of space, mentioning `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` is redundant. An otherwise excellent answer man. +1. Found your answer here a bit lacking though: [Strange thread behavior with onClickListener](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18192427/2558882).

Comment: Allright thank you for your explaination, I edited my answer could you please check if its correct. Lol, definitely not my best answer there, I just thought it didn't deserve -1 :-)

Comment: Phil, setting parent view's `layout_height` to `0dp` is counter-productive. The view would disappear. The `layout_weight` is used to distribute space _within_ the parent. How you allot the space to the parent is whole another issue. For the purpose of providing an example, revert LinearLayout's `android:layout_height` to `wrap_content` (you had the correct value before). The child's (i.e. Button's) attributes are correct. If there were more children, their `layout_widths` would also be `0dp` since children would be added _side by side_(parent's orientation is currently horizontal).

Comment: Aaaaah now I get it, thank you again :) I actually thought its quite strange to set the height to 0dp, but I guess I misunderstood you :)

Comment: If the parent's orientation was `vertical`, we would be using `layout_height="0dp"` for the children. Because, children will be added `on top of each other`. Think of it this way: When parent's orientation is `horizontal`, `layout_weight` distributes extra (unused) space horizontally. When parent's orientation is `vertical`, `layout_weight` distributes extra (unused) space vertically.